# Gitlab CI: change pipeline definition dynamically

Tags: terraform, gitlab, pipeline

I need to pass info from stage A to stage B so I can change stage B dynamically.

Details:

- I have a stage (A) where I validate a terraform plan and check if
  it's going to destroy resources.
- I have another stage (B), which applies the terraform plan, which I want to be triggered manually if stage A detected that resources are going to be destroyed.
- When nothing is being destroyed the terraform apply stage (B) should run automatically

How can I pass this information from stage A to B?

Making an artifact in A and using "rules:exist" in stage B is not possible, [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215100)

And if I understand the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) correctly it's not possible to use a "dotenv" var in the "rules:if" section of stage B.

It seems like Gitlab doesn't want you to change the pipeline definition dynamically.
Maybe there is a practical solution that I'm not aware of to solve this usecase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't use `dotenv` variables in the `rules` clause(s) is that `rules` are evaluated before the pipeline even starts executing.

If you have a `rules` clause like

```yml
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG === 'v1.0.0'
  when: never
  - when: always
```

Gitlab CI will check the following things:

1. Is the pipeline a `Tag Pipeline` (from the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable)? If no, `CI_COMMIT_TAG` won't exist, so the clause doesn't exist, and `when:always` is the only rule. Add the job to the pipeline.
2. If the pipeline is a tag pipeline, is the tag === 'v1.0.0'? Then use `when:never`. Don't add the job to the pipeline.
3. Tag pipeline and the tag !== 'v1.0.0', use `when:never` and add the job to the pipeline.

All these things happen before the pipeline is in the `created` state, so therefore it cannot depend on a variable that is created once the pipeline starts running.

Knowing this, the way I would solve the problem is to mark the job in Stage B as a manual job like it already is, but when you want to run it automatically, call the Gitlab Jobs API from the Stage A job to run the Stage B job.

This will use a couple of API Calls:

1. First, we need to get the jobs for this particular Pipeline:

```bash
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_IID/jobs?scope=manual"
```

This will return all the `manual` jobs from the pipeline. If you have more than one, you can retrieve the correct one by looking at the value for `stage` and `name` from the response. Here's an example from the docs:

```json
[
  {
    "commit": {
      "author_email": "admin@example.com",
      "author_name": "Administrator",
      "created_at": "2015-12-24T16:51:14.000+01:00",
      "id": "0ff3ae198f8601a285adcf5c0fff204ee6fba5fd",
      "message": "Test the CI integration.",
      "short_id": "0ff3ae19",
      "title": "Test the CI integration."
    },
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": false,
    "created_at": "2015-12-24T15:51:21.727Z",
    "started_at": "2015-12-24T17:54:24.729Z",
    "finished_at": "2015-12-24T17:54:24.921Z",
    "duration": 0.192,
    "queued_duration": 0.023,
    "artifacts_expire_at": "2016-01-23T17:54:24.921Z",
    "tag_list": [
      "docker runner", "ubuntu18"
    ],
    "id": 6,
    "name": "rspec:other",
    "pipeline": {
      "id": 6,
      "project_id": 1,
      "ref": "main",
      "sha": "0ff3ae198f8601a285adcf5c0fff204ee6fba5fd",
      "status": "pending"
    },
    "ref": "main",
    "artifacts": [],
    "runner": null,
    "stage": "test",
    "status": "failed",
    "tag": false,
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/-/jobs/6",
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Administrator",
      "username": "root",
      "state": "active",
      "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
      "web_url": "http://gitlab.dev/root",
      "created_at": "2015-12-21T13:14:24.077Z",
      "bio": null,
      "location": null,
      "public_email": "",
      "skype": "",
      "linkedin": "",
      "twitter": "",
      "website_url": "",
      "organization": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Once we have the Job ID, we can call the Play Job API:

```bash
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/$ID_OF_STAGE_B_JOB/play"
```

Note: we don't want to use the Predefined Variable `$CI_JOB_ID` for the Play Job API since that will be the ID of the Stage A job, not the Stage B job.

Here's the [Pipeline Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs), and here's the [Play Job API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#play-a-job) for more information and query parameters.